# Converting pdf(encoding:UniJIS-UCS2-H) to base64

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, xmlhttprequest, base64

I have a pdf with encoding UniJIS-UCS2-H.  i want to convert it in to base 64 in javascript.
i wrote the code like this. It converting it in to pdf but the content is not visible.
my code is showing below.

```
function getBinary(file){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    xhr.open("GET", file, false);  
   xhr.overrideMimeType("application/pdf; charset=UniJIS-UCS2-H");  
    xhr.send(null);
    return xhr.responseText;
}

function base64encode(binary) {
    return btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(binary)));
}

var binary = getBinary('http://localhost/first.pdf');
var base64encoded = base64encode(binary);
data = "data:application/pdf;base64,"+base64encoded;
```

the data is  contain only a plain pdf. how can i resolve it ?